# Reduce dataframe using a running flag

Tags: python, pandas, reduce

I have a dataframe with `x`, `y` coordinates of some points. Every point (coordinate pair) is also tagged with a True/False flag:

```
xs = [1,3,7,5,4,6,2,8,9,0]
ys = [0,7,4,5,2,6,9,1,3,8]
flags = [True,False,False,False,True,True,False,True,True,True]
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':xs, 'y':ys,'flag':flags})


    x   y   flag
0   1   0   True
1   3   7   False
2   7   4   False
3   5   5   False
4   4   2   True
5   6   6   True
6   2   9   False
7   8   1   True
8   9   3   True
9   0   8   True
```

**What reduce function can be used to compute 2 total distances:**

1) Total distance for routes that start with a True point right after False point or with a very first point that is True, include all True points and terminate with a False point or end of all points

2) Total distance for routes that start with a False point right after True point or with a very first point that is False, include all False points and terminate with a True point or end of all points

In this example, the follwing sections need to be summed up to get total distances:

```
1) Route built from  True points:
(1,0) - (3,7)
---
(4,2) - (6,6)
(6,6) - (2,9)
---
(8,1) - (9,3)
(9,3) - (0,8)

2) Route built from False points:
(3,7) - (7,4)
(7,4) - (5,5)
(5,5) - (4,2)
---
(2,9) - (8,1)
```

So, for example, with these points:

```
points = [((1,0),(3,7)), ((4,2),(6,6)), ((6,6),(2,9)), 
           ((8,1),(9,3)), ((9,3),(0,8))]

# Compute distance between two points:
def distance(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    return math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)
```

Total distance:

```
total_distance = 0
for t in points:
   total_distance += distance(t[0][0],t[0][1], t[1][0],t[1][1])  

print(total_distance)

29.283943962766887
```

How to calculate distances with a reduce function, not using `pandas.DataFrame.iterrows` ?

Comment: " routes that start with a True point right after False point *or with a very first point that is True*,"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can calculate the distance in a vectorize way with `shift`:

```
df['dist'] = np.sqrt((df['x']-df['x'].shift(-1))**2 + (df['y']-df['y'].shift(-1))**2)
```

then you can create a mask to meet the True condition with `cumsum` and `diff` on the column flag:

```
mask_true = df['flag'].cumsum().diff().fillna(df['flag']).gt(0)
# now use loc to select these rows and the dist column plus sum
print (df.loc[mask_true,'dist'].sum())
# 29.283943962766887
```

for the False condition, then I guess it is the complementary, so you get:

```
print (df.loc[~mask_true,'dist'].sum())
# 20.39834563766817
```

EDIT: sometimes, easiest solution does not come first, but actually, `mask_true` is `df['flag']` so once you have created the column dist, you can do directly:

```
print (df.loc[df['flag'],'dist'].sum())
# 29.283943962766887
print (df.loc[~df['flag'],'dist'].sum())
# 20.39834563766817
```

Comment: nice answer here!

Comment: @ansev thanks, but it was even more simple than that ;)

Comment: Any update on a simpler version of your answer? Thanks!

Comment: @dokondr what do you mean? the fact that df['flag'] is actually enough for masking the column 'dist' is the si;pler versnio :)

Comment: It is not very clear what `cumsum().diff().fillna(df['flag']).gt(0)` does. Difference of Cumulative sum of `flag` values ? Filling NaN with what? How this  expression can be translated to English humans use? Thanks!

Comment: @dokondr so `cumsum` means that every time you have a `True` in the column, the value increase of 1 so first `True` you get 1 then second `True` you get 2, etc and if you have `False` between `True`s, then they have the same value than the previous row. by doing `diff`, it ends up to be 0 if two consecutive rows have same value meaning of `False` in this row and `diff` gives one where there is an increase of value, meaning of a `True`. The `fillna` was to populate the first row that went missing by using `diff` and finally `gt(0)` will give `True` if the value >0 and `False` otherwise.

Comment: @dokondr so you actually ends up with the same column than `df['flag']`, if you do `(df['flag']==df['flag'].cumsum().diff().fillna(df['flag']).gt(0)).all()` you will get `True`, the creation of `mask_true` is not necessary because it is exactly as `df['flag']`